# Visits before conversions in BigQuery, for only a specific URL

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

Sitting with Google Analytics 360 standard export in BigQuery and need a nudge in the right direction.
I´m looking to query out how many visits a user has before a conversion is made. This is available in GA directly but i only want to count visits on a specific URL.

The result should be like:

```
Visits_before_conversions, Conversions 
1, 23
2, 58
3, 89
4, 20
```

My ideas so far:
Select all sessions that visited a specific URL and the userID had a conversion.
Sort them om visittime to get the correct sequence of visits.

But this is where it gets tricky, because a user can continue to visit the site after the conversion have happened. So i can´t just count the visits. 
A journey could be visit, visit, visit, visit with conversion, visit, visit with conversion, etc... 
So after a user makes a conversion their visit counter should be set to 0 and a new conversion journey stars.

Any tips?

Comment: Are you using user id views? So, basically every session has a user id information? Or how do you identify a user, maybe fullvisitorid?

Comment: Yes i will have to use fullVisitorId

Comment: How do you define conversions?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data and the query that you came up with until now?

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you want to filter the users that visited '/home' at least once. For this purpose, I calculated the number of visits to '/home' path in home_visits column.

My second filter is, users with at least one transactions. In having part of the query, I used `SUM(totals.transactions) > 0` to filter these players.

Also, I used google analytics sample data for the date 20170801. Don't forget to change the table name to yours and include all the days you want to query.

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UNNEST(visits) as v WHERE v < first_transaction_time) visits_before_trx
FROM (
  SELECT 
    fullVisitorId, 
    ARRAY_AGG(visitStartTime order by visitStartTime) as visits, 
    count(*) as nr_visits,
    SUM((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE page.pagePath = '/home')) as home_visits,
    MIN(CASE WHEN totals.transactions > 0 THEN visitStartTime END ) as first_transaction_time
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801`
  group by 1
  having SUM(totals.transactions) > 0
    AND home_visits > 0
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

With this approach I'm creating a new array containing the journeys from transaction to transaction. But it contains only visits with a certain page or if it has a transaction.

```sql
DECLARE myPath DEFAULT '/home';

WITH t AS (
  SELECT 
    fullvisitorid,
    ARRAY_AGG(
      STRUCT( /*data we need later: time, visits with page, transactions - all in one array */
        TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitstarttime) AS visitstarttime,
        (SELECT IF(COUNT(*)>0,1,0) FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE page.pagePath = myPath) AS sawMyPath,
        IF(totals.transactions>0,1,0) AS hasTransactions
      ) ORDER BY visitstarttime ASC
    ) as visits
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170*`
  WHERE
    totals.transactions>0
    OR
    (SELECT COUNT(*)>0 FROM unnest(hits) WHERE page.pagePath = myPath)
  GROUP BY 1
)

SELECT 
  fullvisitorid, 
  ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT 
    *,
    /* Create a journey id by cumulating the order info backwards
     * use this id in GROUP BY later to count your visits  
     */
    SUM(hasTransactions) OVER (ORDER BY visitstarttime DESC) AS journeyId
  FROM UNNEST(visits) ORDER BY visitstarttime ASC) AS visitsWithId
FROM t
WHERE
  (select count(*)>0 FROM unnest(visits) where hasTransactions>0)
LIMIT 1000
```

I'm not sure where you want to go from there, but you should be able to calculate everything you need from that array. (The query only shows visitors with any transactions atm).

I hope this gives you the right nudge :)